# Probability of getting $5$ heads on $10$ (fair) coin flips?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Even before attempting the problem, I immediately defaulted to an answer: $\frac{1}{2}$.

I thought that this was a possible answer since the probability of flipping a head on one flip is definitely $\frac{1}{2}$.

I then worked through the problem:

Let E be the event in the problem statement.

The total number of possible outcomes of $10$ coin flips: $N = 2^{10}$

The total number of ways in which E can result:for $n=10,r=5, nCr= 252$

$P(E) =\frac{n}{N} = .246$

How do I correct my intuition?

Comment: `How do I correct my intuition?`  Well, you worked through the problem correctly.  Perhaps any time you *feel* like an answer should be something, ask yourself *why* you think that and if it makes sense mathematically.  Certainly there are several scenarios that our intuition is correct (*e.g. there are as many sequences which start with heads as sequences which start with tails*), but increasing the accuracy of your intuition comes with practice/understanding.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you got - 0.246 is the probability of getting 'exactly' 5 heads. Your intuition gives the 'Expectation' E(x). When 10 coins are tossed, the Expectation is that you get 5 heads. Your intuition makes an average of all the cases while the solution takes only the cases where number of heads is 'exactly' 5.

Let me give you another problem- What is the probability that number of heads is greater than number of tails? This is the question which your intuition answered.

Comment: For an odd number of coin tosses, heads > tails is exactly a probability of 1/2. For 10 coin tosses, it is only 0.377, because 5 heads and 5 tails each is 0.246.

Comment: @CJDennis I think you are mistaken. It's not just 5 heads and 5 tails, it also includes 6heads, 4 tails, ; 7 heads, 3 tails; etc....  all the cases where heads are more than tails.

Comment: You can only get a 50/50 split if it's not possible to get an equal number of heads and tails. For all even numbers of coin tosses there is aways a chance that exactly half will be heads and half will be tails. For odd numbers of coin tosses it's impossible to have an equal number of head and tails. E.g. for 11, the closest you can get is 5 heads, 6 tails or 6 heads, 5 tails. For 10 tosses, the probability of fewer heads than tails is 0.377, equal number of heads and tails 0.246, more heads than tails 0.377 for a total of 1.

Answer (score 1):

can also be expressed as a binomial distribution which simplifies to the same but is ${10\choose 5}({1\over 2})^5({1\over 2})^5$.  but this way if the probability was not $1\over 2$ could still calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine a case with $4$ rolls where we desire $2$ heads (MathJax diagrams only go so far...)
$$\newcommand{\mychoose}[2]{\bigl({{#1}\atop#2}\bigr)}$$
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}  & & &   &  &  &  &  H & & & & & \\
& & &   &  &   & \swarrow &   & \searrow &  \\
& &   &   &   & H &   &   &   & T &  \\
& & &   &  \swarrow & \downarrow &   &   &   & \downarrow & \searrow \\ 
& & & H  &   & T &   &   &   & H &  & T \\
& & \swarrow  & \downarrow  &  & \downarrow  & \searrow  &   & \swarrow & \downarrow &  & \downarrow & \searrow \\
 & H  &   & T &  & H  &  \color{red}{T} &  & H & \color{red}{T} &  & \color{red}{H} & & T\end{array}$$
  $$ $$
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}  & & &   &  &  &  &  T & & & & & \\
& & &   &  &   & \swarrow &   & \searrow &  \\
& &   &   &   & H &   &   &   & T &  \\
& & &   &  \swarrow & \downarrow &   &   &   & \downarrow & \searrow \\ 
& & & H  &   & T &   &   &   & H &  & T \\
& & \swarrow  & \downarrow  &  & \downarrow  & \searrow  &   & \swarrow & \downarrow &  & \downarrow & \searrow \\
 & H  &   & \color{red}{T} &  & \color{red}{H}  &  T &  & \color{red}{H} & T &  & H & & T\end{array}$$

Thus, we have a $\frac{6}{16} = \frac{3}{8}$ chance of getting two heads from four rolls by analyzing our diagram; this can also be found by taking $\frac{\mychoose{2}{4}}{2^4} = \frac{6}{16} = \frac{3}{8}$. As an addendum, note that your intuition calculation gives the chance that you get either $2$ ***or*** $1$ head from $4$ rolls ( $= \frac{8}{16} = \frac{1}{2}$ which can be easily identified from the diagram). Now just apply the logic from this example to your $10$ roll case. Also, pushing MathJax diagrams this far is a pain. You have been warned.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to solve this, but I like the following one:

I assume that you meant to say exactly 5 heads. Then what does such a toss look like? For instance, it could be:

$$HHTHTTTHTH$$

where H means you tossed a head, and T a tail. So now all the possibilities you have are the combinations of this sequence, hence $\frac{10!}{5!5!} = 252$ possibilities. Now all the possibilities are $2^{10} = 1024$. So the probability is $$\frac{252}{1024} = \frac{63}{256} \simeq 0.246$$

I like that method. It's not the fastest one, but easily explained to anyone, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your intuition by considering extreme versions of the original problem. If you had to toss a coin two million times, would your intution suggest that the chance is $1/2$ that you'll get exactly a million heads? No, because in many tosses, there is 'chance variation' that prevents you from getting exactly half heads and half tails. Also, if the chance is $1/2$ of getting exactly a million heads, then it follows that *all other possibilities* collectively must have a probability of $1/2$, which also doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly 5 heads and 5 tails, the score after 9 tosses has to be 5-4 one way or the other.  In this case, there is a $50\%$ chance you get to 5-5.  On the other hand if you aren't at 5-4 (one way or the other) after 9 flips, there is no chance of getting a 5-5 split.  So certainly the chance of 5-5 is less than $0.5$.